# Como cambiar el ancho de mi grafica al exportarla con highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

el highcharts trae una opción para poder exportar mi gráfica en diferentes formatos ejemplo (PNG,JPG entre otros), eso se encuentra en la parte superior derecha en el menu de 3 lineas.

Como puedo hacer para aumentar el ancho de mi gráfica al exportarla en cualquiera de esos formatos:

Actualmente el problema que tengo es que al exportar la gráfica y abrir la imagen no me muestra el dato del Spline en el ultimo mes, y necesito que muestre todos los datos que no quede ninguno sin verse.

Pueden hacer la prueba exportando la grafica en algun formato puede ser en PNG y alli se daran de cuenta que en el ultimo mes no me muestra el valor de los kilometrajes al final.

```js
Highcharts.chart('rotacionanio240', {
 colors: ['#00ff6c','#03deec','#f5940a'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'ROTACIONES - FLOTA: <b>240</b> ACUMULADO'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Acumulado - Período: 2019'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Km rotación',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: 'Cantidad de llantas',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    
 opposite: true,
            max: 300,
            min: 0,
            startOnTick: false
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',

            },
        }
    },legend: {
            align: 'center',
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Cantidad',
  color: '#6de8f0',
  yAxis: 1,
  
data: [
                [
                    '2019-01',
                    55
                ],
                [
                    '2019-02',
                    72
                ],
                [
                    '2019-03',
                    54
                ],
                [
                    '2019-04',
                    51
                ],
                [
                    '2019-05',
                    68
                ],
                [
                    '2019-06',
                    33
                ],
                [
                    '2019-07',
                    51
                ],
                [
                    '2019-08',
                    86
                ],
                [
                    '2019-09',
                    38
                ],
                [
                    '2019-10',
                    51
                ],
                [
                    '2019-11',
                    26
                ],

            ],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
   color: 'black'
        }
    },{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'KM',
  color: '#03deec',
  
data: [
                [
                    '2019-01',
                    30262
                ],
                [
                    '2019-02',
                    32000
                ],
                [
                    '2019-03',
                    28368
                ],
                [
                    '2019-04',
                    28991
                ],
                [
                    '2019-05',
                    27050
                ],
                [
                    '2019-06',
                    28323
                ],
                [
                    '2019-07',
                    31218
                ],
                [
                    '2019-08',
                    27697
                ],
                [
                    '2019-09',
                    26401
                ],
                [
                    '2019-10',
                    25961
                ],
                [
                    '2019-11',
                    25480
                ],
            ],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
   color: 'red'
        }
    },
  ]
 
});
```

```html
<div id="rotacionanio240" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:20px;"></div>


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes arreglar tu problema cambiando el tamaño del font a 10px asi:

```js
Highcharts.chart('rotacionanio240', {
 colors: ['#00ff6c','#03deec','#f5940a'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'ROTACIONES - FLOTA: <b>240</b> ACUMULADO'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Acumulado - Período: 2019'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Km rotación',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: 'Cantidad de llantas',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    
 opposite: true,
            max: 300,
            min: 0,
            startOnTick: false
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',

            },
        }
    },legend: {
            align: 'center',
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Cantidad',
  color: '#6de8f0',
  yAxis: 1,
  
data: [
                [
                    '2019-01',
                    55
                ],
                [
                    '2019-02',
                    72
                ],
                [
                    '2019-03',
                    54
                ],
                [
                    '2019-04',
                    51
                ],
                [
                    '2019-05',
                    68
                ],
                [
                    '2019-06',
                    33
                ],
                [
                    '2019-07',
                    51
                ],
                [
                    '2019-08',
                    86
                ],
                [
                    '2019-09',
                    38
                ],
                [
                    '2019-10',
                    51
                ],
                [
                    '2019-11',
                    26
                ],

            ],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
   color: 'black'
        }
    },{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'KM',
  color: '#03deec',
  
data: [
                [
                    '2019-01',
                    30262
                ],
                [
                    '2019-02',
                    32000
                ],
                [
                    '2019-03',
                    28368
                ],
                [
                    '2019-04',
                    28991
                ],
                [
                    '2019-05',
                    27050
                ],
                [
                    '2019-06',
                    28323
                ],
                [
                    '2019-07',
                    31218
                ],
                [
                    '2019-08',
                    27697
                ],
                [
                    '2019-09',
                    26401
                ],
                [
                    '2019-10',
                    25961
                ],
                [
                    '2019-11',
                    25480
                ],
            ],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 5,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
         color: 'red',
            style: {
                fontSize: '10px'
            }
        }
    },
  ]
 
});
```

```html
<div id="rotacionanio240" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:20px;"></div>


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Listo, me sirvio de mucho, muchas gracias.